# Create a object that belongs to two other objects

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I'm creating a simple api using sequelize.js V.5 for posting comments of books. The comment should belong to the book through the book id and the same for the user that posted.

I'm not quite sure how to create this.

```
//user model
...
User.hasMany(models.Comment)
...

//book model
...
Book.hasMany(models.Comment);
...

//comment model
...
Comment.belongsTo(models.User);
Comment.belongsTo(models.Book);
...
//route
...
Comment.create(
    {
        //what do i put here? or what other syntax i use
     }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc you need to associate objects

Standard example straight from the doc

**Associating objects**

```
Because Sequelize is doing a lot of magic, you have to call Sequelize.sync after setting the associations! Doing so will allow you the following:

Project.belongsToMany(Task)
Task.belongsToMany(Project)

Project.create()...
Task.create()...
Task.create()...

// save them... and then:
project.setTasks([task1, task2]).then(function() {
  // saved!
})

// ok, now they are saved... how do I get them later on?
project.getTasks().then(function(associatedTasks) {
  // associatedTasks is an array of tasks
})

// You can also pass filters to the getter method.
// They are equal to the options you can pass to a usual finder method.
project.getTasks({ where: 'id > 10' }).then(function(tasks) {
  // tasks with an id greater than 10 :)
})

// You can also only retrieve certain fields of a associated object.
project.getTasks({attributes: ['title']}).then(function(tasks) {
    // retrieve tasks with the attributes "title" and "id"
})
```

**To remove created associations you can just call the set method without a specific id:**

```
// remove the association with task1
project.setTasks([task2]).then(function(associatedTasks) {
  // you will get task2 only
})

// remove 'em all
project.setTasks([]).then(function(associatedTasks) {
  // you will get an empty array
})

// or remove 'em more directly
project.removeTask(task1).then(function() {
  // it's gone
})

// and add 'em again
project.addTask(task1).then(function() {
  // it's back again
})
```

**So as to your problem:**

there must be something like:

```
Comment.create(
    {
        // create new comment as you like
     }
```

and then something like (as needed)

```
comment.setUser(user).then(function() {
  // saved!
})

comment.setBook(book).then(function() {
  // saved!
})
```

Comment: This should work, but I rather use foreign keys as a not null column especially  because all comments MUST be related to a book and a user as a PO constraint. 
I was looking for a solution that creates the comment and add the foreign  keys at the same time to prevent the db from refusing the data